# Karate: Is there a way to mask console logs of a specific scenario?

Tags: hide, karate, console.log, masking

I have some sensitive information in my test scripts, while executing the tests those are printing in the console log do I would like to mask console log for a specific scenario alone.

Please let me know if possible. I have looked at the example given in github but it doesn't help much as it's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, please refer the documentation here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#report-verbosity

And if you use the tag `@report=false` for a `Scenario` (or even `Feature`) it should hide the logs only for that one.

If the above two suggestions don't help - please assume that what you want is NOT supported and either contribute code, or look for another tool - thanks.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to mask specific values in the console log? In few cases, I don't want to mask the complete console log.

Comment: @Prabhu yes if you are able to read the docs and do some Java programming, else the answer is NO: https://github.com/intuit/karate#log-masking